# Global exception middleware in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-middleware

So I'm implementing a global exception middleware once again. This is nothing new and there are lots of [guides](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/17/net-6-global-error-handler-tutorial-with-example) out there for it, however, this time I want to log which class and which method caused the exception. Currently in the application we have something like this for every function:

```
try
{
    //Do your stuff here.
}
catch (HttpOperationException ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"{GetType().Name}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} failed: {ex.Response.Content}");
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"{GetType().Name}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} failed: {ex}");
    throw;
}
```

I want to use a global exception handler middleware instead, but I've run across a problem, once I'm outside the scope of where the exception occurs in the code, I lose access to an accurate way to tell which class and method the exception occurred in.

Sure, I could use the stack trace, but I don't really feel comfortable with using the stack trace string to get the class and method where the error occurred. I've also tried relocating my middleware to be next to the controller mapping, like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

and then try to get the reflection values from the Request delegate in my middleware like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    _next = next;
}

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //These are not the correct values as explained before.
            var errorClass = _next.Target.GetType();
            var errorMethod = _next.Method;

            var response = context.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";

            switch (ex)
            {
                case HttpOperationException e:
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                logger.LogError($"{errorClass.Name}.{errorMethod.Name} failed: {e.Response.Content}");
                    break;
                case Exception e:
                    logger.LogError($"{errorClass.Name}.{errorMethod.Name} failed: {ex}");
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    break;
            }

            var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { message = ex?.Message });
            await response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
}
```

But the class in reflection that I get is the Endpoints middleware (though this makes sense), not the controller or the class that the error occurred in. Is there a way to get this the way I'm trying to do it or is this impossible within middleware?

Edit: In summary, what I want is to find a way to not have to repeat the try catch and logging code all the time, since it's the same almost everywhere. Maybe a middleware isn't the answer here, I'm open to alternatives.

Thanks,

Comment: I try to use reflection in middleware and i get the same result as yours, In my opinion, If you want to get concrete classes and methods which caused the error, `stacktrace` isn't a easy and quick method?

Comment: I might end up doing that, but I wanted to know if anyone knew of a better way than to parse the string.